# Wordpress contact form 7 doesnt work normaly why?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

When I press the “*send*” button, the contact form just hangs with two spinning arrows. After about *1 minute* or so, there is a **504 error**, and then the mail is sent and received and looks the way it is supposed to look.

Even though the mail is sent when the *504 error occurs*, the spinning arrows just keep spinning with no indication that the message has been sent. If the user gets tired of the spinning icon and starts pressing the send button several times to try and speed things up, we get lots of emails. But still no indication that a mail has been sent, and there is still no end to the spinning arrows.
my site - *bilim.astana.kz*  ( right bottom form )

Comment: are you here?..

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line `data: urlencodeFormData(formData),` and add `urlencodeFormData` this function at end.

```
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute(
            '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId( $form ) + '/feedback' ),
        data: urlencodeFormData(formData),
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    } ).done( function( data, status, xhr ) {
        ajaxSuccess( data, status, xhr, $form );
        $( '.ajax-loader', $form ).removeClass( 'is-active' );
    } ).fail( function( xhr, status, error ) {
        var $e = $( '<div class="ajax-error"></div>' ).text( error.message );
        $form.after( $e );
    } );



function urlencodeFormData(fd){
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    for(var pair of fd.entries()){
    typeof pair[1]=='string' && params.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }
    return params.toString();
}
```

Comment: 400 (Bad Request) 
Thnx for try)